# jQuery script is loaded but nothing happen

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, lazy-loading, jquery-lazyload

Im using this script (following a video tutorial) but nothing happens and I have no error:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
var windowSize = $(window).height();
var appart = 50;

display(scrollTop, windowSize);

$(window).resize(function(){
    var windowSize = $(window).height();
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    display(scrollTop, windowSize);
});

function display(scrollTop, windowSize){

    $('.wp-post-image').each(function(){

        var elemTop = $(this).offset().top;

        if($(this).css('opacity') === 0 && (parseInt(elemTop) <= parseInt(scrollTop + windowSize - appart))){

            $(this).fadeTo(2000,1);

        }   

    }); 

}   

});
```

Its supposed to display my content with transition when scrolling on the page (like lazy loading).

Im using wordpress.

I really don't understand why it does not work.
Thank you.

Comment: Change `$(document).ready(function ()` to `jQuery(document).ready(function ($)`

Comment: Doesn't change anything. Script seems to be loaded correctly. Also, other scripts works fine. I tried to delete all the other scripts except this one but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I see. `$(this).css('opacity') === 0` at this line. `$(this).css('opacity')` actually return `"0"`. so, you need change `===` to `==`

Comment: Also need to remove the `var` inside your `resize` handler so it sets the higher scoped variable rather than a newly created local variable that is immediately discarded.

Comment: This looks wrong too: `parseInt(scrollTop + windowSize - appart)`.  If those values are numbers (which they appear to be), there's no need for `parseInt()`.  Also remove `parseInt()` from this: `parseInt(elemTop)`.

Comment: look this http://jsfiddle.net/uoryon/xLk34t27/2/ I write a correct version for you.

Comment: It was the "===" . Now it works, thank you !

Comment: Additionally, always specify the second parameter when using parseInt(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) of the WordPress Codex:

> The jQuery library included with WordPress is set to use the `noConflict()` mode to prevent compatibility issues with other JavaScript libraries that WordPress can use.
>
> In the `noConflict()` mode, the global `$` shortcut for jQuery is not available, so you need to use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(#somefunction) ...
});
```

> However, if you would prefer to use the short `$` instead of `jQuery`, you can use the following wrapper around your code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
});
```

Hope that helps.